# NSDate returns UnDesired Date formate while Converting string From date

Tags: iphone

I am trying to convert NSString from NSdate, in that when I try to covert string `2011-10-10` to `nsdate`  , it returns **2011-10-09 18:30:00 +0000** as date , I am doing in xcode 3.2.5 and in simulator.

Here is my code

```
+(NSDate *)ConverStringToDate:(NSString *)str_Date
 {
   NSDateFormatter * lastFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [lastFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
   [lastFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
   lastDate = [lastFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-10-10"];
   return lastDate;
}
```

The Last date is not proper. Please help me from this issue.

Comment: This has been covered extensively here - see the duplicate question above. When you log an NSDate, it shows a standard output in UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the locale as US, it makes up for the time difference by default. It probably returns a date which is valid in your time zone (the one your device is set up as, where are you?). There's a question about time zones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846144/nsdate-format-issue).